# django humanize timesince do not printing

Tags: django, web, django-models, django-templates

My django view is passing this inside my template:

```
context={'material':material_id,'inventory_list':inventory,'now_time':datetime.now()
```

Inside my material object I have this field that is update each new save:

```
last_update = models.DateTimeField()
```

And I'm trying to print an humanized time ago in the screen so I'm doing this:

```
{{now_time | timesince:material.last_update }}
```

It's not printing anything, despite separately both variables are appearing correctly:

```
{{now_time}} {{material.last_update}}
OUTPUT:
May 18, 2018, 11:10 a.m. May 18, 2018, 10:45 a.m.
```

Here is my complete view:

```
def material_page(request,pk):
try:
    material_id=Material.objects.get(id=pk)
    inventory = InventoryMove.objects.filter(material=material_id).order_by("-date")
    i=0
    for movement in inventory:
        print (inventory[i].date)
        i+=1
except Material.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Material does not exist")
return render(
     request,
    'material_detail.html',
    context={'material':material_id,'inventory_list':inventory,'now_time':datetime.now()}
    )
```

Comment: But `material` is not the material, but the `_id` of the material.